# Calculating the probability distribution for Hardware defects based on history of defects

Tags: distributions, hazard, engineering-statistics

I'm writing a study about Hardware status in my institution.

I've gathered data about hardware failures over time (I know how many failures happened each semester each year on a specific hardware model) and I want to predict the chance that other failures may happen in the future, considering that, over time, the hardware is more probable of failing.

I've read about Hazard functions but couldn't really understand how to apply it.

My data is the following:

```
Semester     Defects    Pct of defects
1/2016          1           0,010
2/2016          0           0,000
1/2017          4           0,072
2/2017          1           0,010
1/2018          4           0,072
2/2018          2           0,020
1/2019          9           0,093
2/2019          2           0,020
```

This is out of a global of 96 machines.

I've compiled this graph from data (maybe it can help):

[image]

I guess I should calculate a probability function based on data and then calculate the distribution, right? But how to do it?

I've also read about Mean time between failures, but I want to make a future prediction based on current failures and some entropy decay model...

Comment: Is that all the data you have, or just an example? For hazard estimates we need not only number of defects, but the number of machines under risk ... (that possibly could have failed)

Comment: Hi khetil. I have the number of machines. I'll add it.